# Rightmove XML Entities

Tags: xml, encoding, drupal-7, html-encode, xml-encoding

We have a site which provides data to Rightmove via an XML file. However, we're seeing a small issue with special characters being displayed with odd symbols. For example, when smart quotes are pasted into our data source (Drupal CMS) the characters display as â€ or â€™.

[image: Example of character issue]

Our database tables are using utf8_general_ci and everything looks fine on our site. What do I need to do to get Rightmove to display the proper characters?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue

I solved it by passing the string thorough  [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) function.
I viewed rightmoves page source and found the character encoding to be iso-8859-1. So used this function as this function also converts  UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1.